# Is It Safe To have 3d View Turning Transition In My App Similar To iBook.

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I Want To Implement 3d View Turning Transition In My App Similar To IBook.
In IBook Transition happened When you Jump From Bookshelf To Store or Store to Bookshelf.
before Implementing it I Want To Know Is It Safe To Have That Transition In My App.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what safe means? Do you mean safe to put on the App Store?

Comment: apple wont reject it (as long as it does not crash!).

Comment: It's safe as long as you're [not using their private api](http://www.imore.com/2010/04/06/ibooks-private-apis/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course!  Apple hasn't kept it a secret, it's just a modalTransitionStyle.
Specifically: `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`

If you want the thick border transition (the wood grain of the shelf), take a look at EPGLTransitions: http://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView